# Only getting one element output from Java servlet parser

Tags: java, servlets, xml-parsing, nodes

I'm trying to get this piece of code to parse an XML-file that is placed on an extern server. The problem is that the output only lists the first result in a table. Any suggestions why this is? The code is quite messy, and I apologize for that. I'm using this code as a school experiment to test parsing through a servlet, and this is basically just a premade servlet I found online, that I am trying to fit into my project.

Would be very grateful if anyone could shed some light onto my problem, or come up with a better solution for solving it!

```
import java.io.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/Veivesen"})

public class Veivesen extends HttpServlet{ 


    public boolean isTextNode(Node n){
        return n.getNodeName().equals("#text");
    }


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try{
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse("http://www.p4.no/rss/trafikk.aspx?area=20");
            out.println("<table border=2><tr><th>Title</th><th>Link</th></tr>");
            Element  element = doc.getDocumentElement(); 
            NodeList newsNodes = element.getChildNodes();
            for (int i=0; i<newsNodes.getLength(); i++){
                Node news = newsNodes.item(i);
                out.println(news);
                if (isTextNode(news))
                    continue;
                NodeList NameDOBCity = news.getChildNodes(); 
                out.println("<tr>");
                for (int j=0; j<NameDOBCity.getLength(); j++ ){
                    Node node = NameDOBCity.item(j);
                    if ( isTextNode(node)) 
                        continue;
                    out.println("<td>"+(node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue())+"</td>");
                    System.out.println(node.getFirstChild());
                } 
                out.println("</tr>");
            }
            out.println("</table>");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a minimal testable code that doesn't any any compilation error.

Comment: I'm not having any complilation errors on my side. You can find the copy I used in the answer section at the page metioned below. Keep in mind that this example uses a local file instead of an URL.

http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JSP-Servlet/20574-read-XML-file-and-display-it-using-java-servlets.html

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is to read the items in the channel of the RSS, you need to find the proper xml elements, try this modified version of your `doGet` method:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse("http://www.p4.no/rss/trafikk.aspx?area=20");
        out.println("<html><body><table border=2><tr><th>Title</th><th>Link</th></tr>");
        Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList channelNodes = element.getElementsByTagName("channel");
        NodeList newsNodes = ((Element)channelNodes.item(0)).getElementsByTagName("item");

        for (int i=0; i<newsNodes.getLength(); i++){
            Node news = newsNodes.item(i);
            //out.println(news);
            if (isTextNode(news))
                continue;
            NodeList NameDOBCity = news.getChildNodes();
            out.println("<tr>");
            for (int j=0; j<NameDOBCity.getLength(); j++ ){
                Node node = NameDOBCity.item(j);
                if ( isTextNode(node))
                    continue;
                out.println("<td>"+(node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue())+"</td>");
                System.out.println(node.getFirstChild());
            }
            out.println("</tr>");
        }
        out.println("</table></body></html>");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, thanks!

Just a follow-up question. While the link I'm using in this one works fine, we seems to having trouble parsing some XML-files, or more specifically this one:
http://www.vegvesen.no/trafikk/xml/savedsearch.xml?id=600

Any thoughts as to why?